# Finding a vector c that bisects two non parallel vector a, b

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

So today my lecturer posted a question.
Suppose a and b are two non-parallel, non-zero 3D vectors, where ||a|| = A , 
||b|| = B. find a pair of real numbers x and y, in terms of A and B, such that the vector c = xa + yb bisects the angle between a and b.

My initial approach:
After drawing out a, b. And using the triangle rule of addition of vectors， I realize the triangle formed by a, b, c is an isosceles triangle. This led me to form the equation:
||xa|| = ||yb|| = xA = yB 
However, I'm stuck after this step. Is my approach wrong, if not whats the next step I should do. Else what would be a correct approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT...consider the **unit** vectors in the direction of a and b and add them to form the diagonal of a rhombus...

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about an isosceles triangle is not correct (if I understand it correctly). The triangle won't be isosceles unless $A$ = $B$.

Here is one possible approach ...

The bisector is the average of the unit vectors parallel to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, which is
$$
\mathbf{c} = \frac12\left(\frac{\mathbf{a}}{A} + \frac{\mathbf{b}}{B}\right)
$$
So, we want
$$
x\mathbf{a} + y\mathbf{b} = \frac12\left(\frac{\mathbf{a}}{A} + \frac{\mathbf{b}}{B}\right)
$$
From this, you can probably figure out what $x$ and $y$ should be.